# Launch and perform action in multiple subdir

Tags: bash

I'm about to launch and perform an action in every subdir on one parent directory using this:

```
for i in ./*/*R1.fastq;
do
    if [ -d "${i}" ]; then
        echo "${i}" 
        python2.7 demultadapt.py -f $i -p Demul-01-R1 FILE_ADAPT
    fi
done
```

`./*/*R1.fastq` are files (not directories) whose names end with `R1.fastq` that are located in subdirectories of the current working directory.

But it doesn't seem to find any files.

Comment: _It never succeed_ is not enough. Please take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at the [asking section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Are the `*R1.fastq` directories or files?

Comment: Hi @Fravadona, its a file. Each subdirectories has a different name, it contains an *R1.fastq file.

Answer (score 0):

Please properly *explain what you are trying to achieve*.

Do you want to act on all directories that contain *R1.fastq files?

```
for f in ./*/*R1.fastq; do
    d=$(dirname "$f")
    echo "$d" 
    python2.7 demultadapt.py -f "$d" -p Demul-01-R1 FILE_ADAPT
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry if it wasn't too clear. So I have multiple subdirectories with different names. On each subdir, it contains a *.R1.fastq file that I want to analyze using above mentioned action. On your code, "dirname" refers to subdirectories or parent folder? Because if its sub dir, I think its not working, because my sub directories has a unique name. Thanks for adding a code.

Comment: `dirname` gets a path of each found file.

Comment: My code seems to reflect your description. But please provide a sample directory tree and a list of commands that are expected to be executed for that sample tree.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this with `find`?

```
find <parent> -type d -print -exec python2.7 demultadapt.py -f {} -p Demul-01-R1 FILE_ADAPT \;
```

Where

- `<parent>` is your starting / parent directory
- `-type d` only return directories
- `-print` print out every hit
- `-exec <command> \;` in each directory execute your command. Note that `{}` will be replaced by the current hit, and the trailing `\;` is required.